# How do I grep second last or nth last character from each line of file

Tags: grep

I want to grep the second last or nth last character from each line of a file.
I'm not able to find how to do this in Linux.

Comment: plz add some example

Comment: Do you want to display *only* the nth-last character of each line?  If so, will you accept other utilities, which may be more suited to the problem than `grep`?

Answer (score 7):

You can anchor the search at the end of the line, and count however many extra characters you want:

```
grep 'X.$'
```

will look for "X" as the second-last character,

```
grep 'X.\{4\}$'
```

will look for "X" as the fifth-last character, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
echo abcdef | grep -Po '.(?=.{1}$)'
```

Output:

```
e
```

---

```
echo abcdef | grep -Po '.(?=.{3}$)'
```

Output:

```
c
```